# Generic type list issue

Tags: c#, generics

I have following structure:

```
public class Base : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class SubBase<T> : Base
{ 
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Values{ get; set; }
    private T selectedValue;
    public T SelectedValue
    {
        get { return selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            selectedValue= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I create lists of BaseFiltr as follows

```
ObservableCollection<BaseFiltr>
```

and then I have one of elements from list which is of type BaseFiltr and I want to get its SelectedValue property but unfortunately it is not possible since it is placed in derived class. I cannot place this property in BaseFiltr since I would have to mark it as generic. BaseFiltr is created only for list's purpose to avoid setting as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<BaseFiltr<some type>>
```

Any suggestions what might be done? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you could elaborate on how exactly you are _using_ that inner property perhaps someone or myself could propose another way of doing it that avoided the need to access the property directly. Since your class is named Filter, I suppose what you want to do is use it to filter a collection of things later on. If that is the case, perhaps you should create a method in your base filter class that receives the collection and then filters it. With that, you could use polymorphism to call this method without needing to know the exact type of filter.

Comment: Name is misleading. Do not pay much attention to it. Every class which dervies from BaseFiltr, like SubBaseFiltr, has its own values (Wartosci) and selected value(WybranaWartosc). The values are sometimes int type, sometimes complex type etc.

Comment: Well fair enough, but still, if you want suggestions of how to achieve this in other ways, we will need to know how it is intended to be used. If you do not provide the context, the only thing I could suggest is to use polymorphism somehow, because it will avoid the need to know what the actual types are by calling a method on the base class. You could also of course put a `object` property on the base class and access it that way, but that would be very cumbersome.

Comment: Also, while we are at it, I seriously recommend you change that title to something more specific to your problem at hand. "Generic type issue" says almost nothing to me. And I wonder if you could give meaningful, English names to those classes and members there.

Comment: My bad. I have just corrected. Hopefully this time I make myself clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> I have one of elements from list which is of type `BaseFiltr` and I want to get its `WybranaWartosc` property

You have a fundamental problem - `BaseFiltr` *does not have* a `WybranaWartosc` property - only `SubBaseFiltr<T>` does.  You *could* check each item to see if it's a `SubBaseFiltr<T>` and *then* cast and probe it's `WybranaWartosc` property.

> BaseFiltr is created only for list's purpose to avoid setting as follows: `ObservableCollection<BaseFiltr<some type>>`

It appears you're sacrificing proper typing for a *slight* decrease in complexity.  If your collection is *really* a collection of `SubBaseFiltr<T>` objects, then *use that type*.

Comment: It is not only SubBase there are more classes this one is only for brevity. Casting is my only way so far but, as I said, I have many classess so casting is unwelcome.

Comment: @Maximus that doesn't change the fact that `BaseFiltr` doesn't have that property - you _could_ do things like add a virtual property, but then `BaseFiltr` would need to be generic as well.  Otherwise you'll have to probe each item to see if it _is_ of a type that has that property.

Comment: I know that. I thought that there is any solution which I have not discovered so far.

Comment: Not cleanly.  There may be workarounds (reflection, `dynamic`), but it sounds like they would just mask a design problem.

Comment: My last idea is to get rid of generic type, add virtual object property which is overriden in derived class and cast to object. Sonner or later I will face casting.

Comment: So what's so bad about casting if you refuse to use proper OOP techniques in the first place?